# Multiple statements in if else statement in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I want to ask is it possible to give multiple statements to be executed when if condition gets satisfied by doing just

```
if[condition] then
statements
else
statements
fi
```

or we have to do something else like using do.....done around that block of statements

Comment: Why not just try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple statements:

```
if [ condition ]; then
  echo 'foo'
  echo 'bar'
else
  echo 'hello'
  echo 'world'
fi
```

Comment: FWIW to Shweta, the statements can also be separated by semicolons.